# Running U-boot standalone API's in spicific core

Tags: boot, bootloader, arm

I am working on Imx6 sabre SD free-scale board, we have u-boot compiled for the board also running an standalone API's(simple hello_world program) from u-boot. But now I want to load & run this standalone application in any of specified core (other then core 0). By default u-boot runs in core 0 of processor.

what are the steps to initialize new core & switch to new core.

Can anyone help me or suggest some reference available.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20055754/1025421). Good luck.

Comment: I have gone through the suggested thread, I need bare-metal reference to switch core with my own standalone program. Can you suggest what are the registers I need to prefer or else any related documents.

Comment: I cannot provide further help, sorry. If you cannot find appropriate documentation, you’ll probably have to contact NXP (now owner of Freescale). Other than that, just look into how Linux does it.

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot itself is always running single threaded on a single CPU core. For most systems U-Boot does not support SMP. Here booting up further CPU cores is left as a task for the operating system. An exception is the x86 architecture.

You could copy a part of the Linux SMP code into your U-Boot application to start extra cores.